# Convert JSON to XML and XML to JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I am converting JSON data to XML node and saving to database while retrieving i need to convert XML to JSON back as same format. Below is the format where it is getting saved.

```
var JSONValue= {{
"key":"ABC",
"value":[
{
"id":1,
"note":"text"
},
{
"id":2,
"note":"text 1"
}
]
}
```

}

```
var xmlDocument=JsonConvert.DesrializeNode("{\"Row\":" + JSONValue +"}",root};

var xmlNode=xmlDocument.InnerXmL;
```

xmlNode will have data in below format and saved to db

```
<Root>
<Row>
<key> ABC</id> 

<value>
<id> 1</id>
<note> text</note>
</value>
<value>
<id> 2</id>
<note> text1</note>
</value>
</Row>
</Root>
```

Tried using this but did not work

```
JsonConvert.serializeNode(xmlNode)
```

Comment: Kindly remind that: Don't construct the JSON your own. The JSON you construct in the parameter of `JsonConvert.DeserializeNode` is not valid. You need a curly braces to wrap `JSONValue`. Since you are constructing the `JSONValue` as anonymous object, you should able to create another object like this: `var root = new { Row = JSONValue }`. And pass it to `JsonConvert.DeserializeNode`.

Comment: yes sorry for the typo it is wrapped inside curly braces

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned that it is not a good practice to constructing the JSON manually, use library to construct the JSON to avoid the syntax issue and save time.

If your `JSONValue` is a string:

1. Read `JSONValue` as `JObject`.
2. Construct a new object that and place the result from (1) inside the `Row` property.
3. Convert to `XNode`.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var rowJson = new
{
    Row = JObject.Parse(JSONValue)
};

var xNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(JObject.FromObject(rowJson).ToString(), "Root");

// To get XML string
Console.WriteLine(xNode.ToString());
```

If your `JSONValue` is an object:

1. Construct a new object and place `JSONValue` inside the `Row` property.
2. Convert to `XNode`.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var rowJson = new
{
    Row = JSONValue
};

var xmlDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(JObject.FromObject(rowJson).ToString(), "Root");

// To get XML string
Console.WriteLine(xNode.ToString());
```

Note that there is no `JsonConvert.DesrializeNode` method, it should be: `JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode`.

Reference: [Convert JSON to XML](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertJsonToXml.htm)